# Pure virtual functions in public API for a shared library (c++)

Tags: c++, linker, polymorphism, linker-errors

I have created a shared library which I am using in another application. One of the core features of the shared library is a base class that check for objects that are being leaked.

The code in the library is as follows:

```
// LeakCheck.hpp
#include <vector>
class LeakCheck
{
private:
    static std::vector<LeakCheck*> objects;
public:
    virtual const char *getClassName() const = 0;
    LeakCheck();
    ~LeakCheck();
    friend class LeakCheckMaster;
};

// LeakCheck.cpp
#include <iostream>
class LeakCheckMaster
{
    ~LeakCheckMaster()
    {
        if (LeakCheck::objects.size()>0) {
            std::cerr << "Leaked objects:" << std::endl;
            for (int i=0; i<LeakCheck::objects.size(); i++)
                std::cerr << LeakCheck::objects[i]->getClassName() << std::endl;
        }
    }
} master;
std::vector<LeakCheck*> LeakCheck::objects;
LeakCheck::LeakCheck()
{
     objects->push_back(this);
}
LeakCheck::~LeakCheck()
{
     objects->remove(this);
}
```

A test application would be:

```
#include "LeakCheck.hpp"


class Test : public LeakCheck
{
    public:
        const char *getClassName() const
        {
             return "Test";
        }
};

int main()
{
    Test *a = new Test();
    return 0
}
```

However, when I try to link the application I get "undefined reference to LeakCheck::getClassName()". I am sure I have linken with the shared library because other functionality work.

This is not the actuall code. I tried to leave only the code essential to the problem. Hope I didn't miss anything.

So why does this linker error occur? If I change it from being pure virtual to return "unnamed class". The output reports all objects as "unnamed class" even though I've implemented the getClassName() function.

Is it not possible to have abstraction across shared library boundaries?

Comment: That last function in LeakCheck.hpp is supposed to be the dtor, right?

Comment: By the way, you use two statically initialized objects (LeakCheck::objects and LeakChecker), and one of them uses another, but the order of their initialization/finalization may be different from desired.

Comment: you know what? you are right. This isn't safe at all. Allright, back to the drawing board.. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

The abstract method must be also virtual: `virtual const char *getClassName() const = 0;`

Comment: sorry.. that was just an oversight when I copied the code, but thanks for pointing it out. Fixed it now. (That was not the cause of the problem)

Comment: Is it `virtual` in your actual code? All these error messages and behaviour when you implement it in the base class look like it's a non-virtual method.

Comment: yes. it is in the actual code. I guess I should have tried to compile it before posting. Sorry about that. Is it even allowed to define a non virtual function to be = 0?